# Coldfusion Link To Previous Page Remembers Text,Radio, and Dropdowns that were chosen

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to create a form with session variables. Where I can link back to the form and show what the user has previously entered. I have figured out a way to show input box values like below:
**INPUT**

```
    <cfif structKeyExists(session, 'firstName')>
        <cfset form_first_name = "#session.firstName#">     
    </cfif>

</cfif>

<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" value="<cfif isDefined("form_first_name")><cfoutput>#form_first_name#</cfoutput></cfif>"  />
```

But I am struggling tremendously on being able to do the same for radio buttons and dropdown menus. Like Below:
**RADIO**

```
<cfif isDefined("session")>

        <cfif structKeyExists(session, 'gender')>
            <cfset form_gender = "#session.gender#">     
        </cfif>

    </cfif>

    <input id="gender" name="gender" type="radio" value="<cfif isDefined("form_gender")><cfoutput>#form_gender#</cfoutput></cfif>"  />Male

    <input id="gender" name="gender" type="radio" value="<cfif isDefined("form_gender")><cfoutput>#form_gender#</cfoutput></cfif>"  />Female
```

**DROPDOWN**

```
<cfif isDefined("session")>

        <cfif structKeyExists(session, 'vehiclebody')>
            <cfset form_vehiclebody = "#session.vehiclebody#">     
        </cfif>

    </cfif>

    <select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody" required>
        <option value="">Select Body</option>
        <option value="2D">2-Door Coupe</option>
        <option value="3D">3-Door Hatchback</option>
        <option value="4D">4-Door Sedan</option>
        <option value="5D">5-Door Hatchback</option>
   </select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @John Whish and I were typing simultaneously, it appears. His answer is more comprehensive, and so I have upvoted it. I see that you are a new user -- so please remember the importance of marking as correct one of the answers you're given (and of upvoting any that you found useful).

Comment: [Joe DeRose](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1944415/joe-derose) Ah yeah, SO needs a 'someone is already answering' notification or something so we don't duplicate each others answers.

Comment: Since you mentioned using a link, I suggest that you use url variables instead of session variables.  Session variables are a bit easier for the user to change in a way you didn't expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Radio

What you need is:

```
<input
    id="gender"
    name="gender"
    type="radio"
    value="Male"
    <cfif isDefined("form_gender") AND form_gender EQ "Male" >checked</cfif>
/>Male
```

**Note:** You changed the `value` field in your example. But you don't want to do that: The value for the field labeled as "Male" should be "Male", and the value for the field labeled as "Female" should be labeled as "Female". Otherwise user selections may not match the labels.

## Dropdown

What you need is:

```
<option
    value="2D"
    <cfif isDefined("session.vehiclebody") AND session.vehiclebody EQ "2D">selected</cfif>
>2-Door Coupe</option>
```

Comment: can you add if its a checkbox by any chance?

Comment: Checkbox uses the same attribute as a radio button: `checked`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something like this:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session, "vehiclebody")>
   <cfset form_vehiclebody = session.vehiclebody>
<cfelse>
   <cfset form_vehiclebody = "">
</cfif>
<cfif structKeyExists(session, "gender")>
   <cfset form_gender = session.gender>
<cfelse>
   <cfset form_gender = "">   
</cfif>

<!--- start your form... --->

<input id="gender" name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" <cfif form_gender eq "Male">checked</cfif>>Male
<input id="gender" name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" <cfif form_gender eq "Female">checked</cfif>>Female

<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody" required>
   <option value=""  <cfif form_vehiclebody eq "">selected</cfif>>Select Body</option>
   <option value="2D" <cfif form_vehiclebody eq "2D">selected</cfif>>2-Door Coupe</option>
   <option value="3D" <cfif form_vehiclebody eq "3D">selected</cfif>>3-Door Hatchback</option>
   <option value="4D" <cfif form_vehiclebody eq "4D">selected</cfif>>4-Door Sedan</option>
   <option value="5D" <cfif form_vehiclebody eq "5D">selected</cfif>>5-Door Hatchback</option>
</select>
```